# Post form get null values in Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, viewmodel

When I submit a form, my Courses List into my ViewModel is getting null values.
This is my ViewModel:

```
public class CandidateViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<CourseViewModel> Courses { get; set; }

    public CandidateViewModel()
    {
        Name = "Kiwanax";
        Courses = new List<CourseViewModel>();
        for (int count = 0; count < 5; ++count)
        {
            Courses.Add(new CourseViewModel( 
                string.Format("Course_{0}", count), 5));
        }
    } 
}

public class CourseViewModel
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public OptionViewModel SelectedOption { get; set; }
    public IList<OptionViewModel> Options { get; set; }

    public CourseViewModel(string name, int numberOfOptions) 
    {
        Name = name;
        Options = new List<OptionViewModel>();
        for (int count = 1; count <= numberOfOptions; ++count)
        {
            Options.Add(new OptionViewModel(count.ToString(), 
                string.Format("Option {0}", count)));
        }
        SelectedOption = Options[0];
    }
}

public class OptionViewModel
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

OK. When I create DropDownLists based on my IList, it works fine.

```
<ul id="cursos">
@for (int count = 0; count < Model.Courses.Count; ++count)
{
    <li>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(i => i.Courses[count].SelectedOption,
            new SelectList(Model.Courses[count].Options, "Value", "Description", Model.Courses[count].SelectedOption))
                @Html.HiddenFor(i => i.Courses[count].ID)
                @Model.Courses[count].Name
            </li>
        }
        </ul>
```

But, when I do post from my form, I'm getting null values from that IList.

Comment: where is this ID coming from in @Html.HiddenFor(i => i.Courses[count].ID) ?

Comment: I putted a property called ID into CourseViewModel. But forgot to write here, sorry.

Comment: And what is this CursosDisponiveis object? Can you show more code? It is hard to tell what is going on?

Comment: Now I fixed my mistakes. I said in the end of the topic: when I do post from my form, that IList named Courses is getting null values. All the properties are null. That's my problem.

Comment: the problem is here `@Html.DropDownListFor(i => i.Courses[count].SelectedOption,` the Right side of the lambda should not be of complex type

Comment: Thanks, 3nigma, it solved one part of my problem. Now, check this out: when I change trhu Javascript anything into this generated selects elemtens, I get null. Eg: When I remove some option trhu JS, I get null on post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot bind dropdowns to complex property values:

```
i => i.Courses[count].SelectedOption
```

It must be bound to the corresponding primitive type that will be sent to the server:

```
i => i.Courses[count].SelectedOption.Value
```

Remember that in HTML the `<select>` element only sends the selected value as a simple string type to the server.

Comment: Thanks, Darin, it solved one of my problems! Now, check this out: when I change trhu Javascript anything into this generated selects elemtens, I get null. Eg: When I remove some option trhu JS, I get null on post! Like: <pre>$("courses li select").each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == -1) $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
})<code>

Comment: If you disable or remove some dropdown from the list you are getting *holes* in the indexes and the default model binder is not able to correctly bind the values. Read the following blog post to understand how binding to collections work: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx. So you have 2 possibilities => 1. fix the indexes of the other select elements (could be hard to achieve) 2. use non sequential indexes in the names of your elements as explained at the end of the previous blog post - In this case you won't care about removing elements.

Comment: Also make sure you have read the following post for a sample implementation of a custom Html.BeginCollectionItem helper which allows you to generate non-sequential indexes: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/